# Multiple archive product exist

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use woocommerce for my e-shop. I don't have that much product at the moment so the pagination on product archive isn't showing up. My archive product page is located on *domain.com/product*, but somehow the page *domain.com/product/page/2* exist while having no products at all in it.
I'm pretty new to wordpress and woocommerce development, can anybody help me?